# Setting the margin in a responsive layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-sm-12 header_site">
     <h1><span class = "header">ABC Company</span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.header_site{
background-color: darkblue;}
.header{
color: white;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 160px;}
```

In the mobile version the layout is as follows: 
[image]

Setting the margin-left: 160px is the problem. But I want the margin-right to be 160px in a desktop computer as follows. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is using **Media Queries** in your CSS, or more preferably **forget the left margin entirely** and wrap your header content into a `.container`.

To do so, construct your HTML like following:

```
<div class="header_site">
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <h1><span class="header">ABC Company</span></h1>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Solve the issue by Media Queries:**

Putting the following tags will keep the margin in Desktop view, but remove it once the screen is too small for it (or adjust the margin a bit lower at that point)

```
@media (min-width: 991px)
{
   .header { margin: 0 0 0 160px; }
}
```

You can set up multiple Media Queries in your CSS and combine min and max values like following:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)
{
   .header { margin: 0 0 0 80px; } /* Your margin is now smaller in tablet view, but returns to the 160 pixels in mobile, not ideal for your situation, but as an example! */
}
```

Comment: Can't I solve this using HTML and CSS ?  not using media queries

Answer (score 1):

Use a media query. It should look like that:

```
.header_site{
background-color: darkblue;}
.header{
color: white;
margin: 0}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
    .header {
        margin: 0 0 0 160px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but you could've opened the media queries a bit more. You should also pay attention to Bootstrap's breakpoints. Pointing the media query to 800px is not recommended, since 991px and 768px breakpoints are so close that are used by Bootstrap's framework.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about that. Thanks for a reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, `margin-left` shouldn't create any problem, but even if it does, CSS has an alternative by using `margin` shorthand. For mobile and desktops, please find the code below:

```
.header_site{
background-color: darkblue;
}

.header {
color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { /*Targetting only mobile devices*/
.header {
    margin: 0 0 0 160px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) { /*Targetting the desktops*/
.header {
    margin: 0 160px 0 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `container` class

```
<div class ="container">
  <div class = "header_site">
     <h1><span class = "header">ABC Company</span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```